# How select multiple tags

Tags: .net, html, dom

I've this code

```
<div id="teste">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> "Lots of HTML TAGS ex: img, href, etc" </tr>
<tr> "Lots of HTML TAGS" </tr>
<tr> "Lots of HTML TAGS" </tr>
<tr> "Lots of HTML TAGS" </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Inside the TR there's a lot of other code..
Sometimes  TR increases : ex: Page 1 there's 5 tr | Page 2 there's 8 tr

I want to take all the TR that are inside the div "teste"-table-tbody... 
that's it..

I trying

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='teste']/table/tbody/tr");`

I want to catch ALL TR tags including other Html tags that are inside the TR

HERE ARE THE CODE THAT IN USE

```
<td align="left" class="portal_table_info_th">
   <div id="teste" style="display:inline;" class="smallfont">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>

           <tr>
           <td class="smallfont alt2">
           <b><center>TUTORIAL CSS</center></b>
           </td>
           <td width="30" class="smallfont">
           <span style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">STATUS</span>
           </td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
           <td class="smallfont alt1"><center><a href="" target="_blank">Tutorial 1</a></center></td>
           <td width="30" class="smallfont"><span style="color:#009933; font-weight:bold">ON</span></td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
           <td class="smallfont alt2"><center><a href="" target="_blank">Tutorial 2</a></center></td>
           <td width="30" class="smallfont"><span style="color:#009933; font-weight:bold">ON</span></td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
           <td class="smallfont alt1"><center><a href="" target="_blank">Tutorial 3</a></center></td>
           <td width="30" class="smallfont"><span style="color:#009933; font-weight:bold">ON</span></td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
           <td class="smallfont alt2"><center><a href="" target="_blank">Tutorial 4</a></center></td>
           <td width="30" class="smallfont"><span style="color:#009933; font-weight:bold">ON</span></td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
           <td class="smallfont alt1"><center><a href="" target="_blank">Tutorial 5</a></center></td>
           <td width="30" class="smallfont"><span style="color:#009933; font-weight:bold">ON</span></td>
           </tr>

        </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</td>
```

HERE are other information...
when i put

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='teste']/table/tbody/tr");
```

DONT WORK , return a null value.
BUT WHEN I PUT

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='teste']");
```

Its works... :/ , But takes all tags.

I try use this and my doc is - ( the data is a HttpGET )

```
doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);
.
.
.
HtmlNodeCollection trtag = doc...
string trtag = doc...
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1) add quotes around the value for id, otherwise it will not be a valid xml markup i.e. id="teste"(this is first reason for the issue and once changed you will get the nodes)

2) Remove the *.

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='teste']/table/tbody/tr");
```

should work..

**EDIT:**
To extract all the tr nodes except the last one use the xpath `"//div[@id='teste']/table/tbody/tr[position()<last()]"` (notice the [position() )

A sample to extract the nodes and convert to string.

```
static void ExtractNodeInfo()
        {
            String xmlText = @"<div id=""teste""> <table> <tbody> <tr> ""Lots of HTML TAGS ex: img, href, etc"" </tr> <tr> ""Lots of HTML TAGS"" </tr> <tr> ""Lots of HTML TAGS"" </tr> <tr> Last ""Lots of HTML TAGS"" </tr> </tbody> </table> </div> ";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//div[@id='teste']/table/tbody/tr[position()<last()]");
            StringBuilder selectedNodesOuter = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder selectedNodesInner = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                selectedNodesOuter.Append(node.OuterXml);
                selectedNodesInner.Append(node.InnerXml);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("######### OUTER XML #########");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(selectedNodesOuter);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("######### INNER XML #########");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(selectedNodesInner);
        }
```

Comment: Still not working... I received value = null .... I want to take ALL TR tags... and the other TAG inside too...

Comment: I am able to get the TR's with what I have suggested. Try it @ http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/

Comment: WHHHHHhHYY!? It WORKS! .... I dont understand o.O.. why here in the VS this query dont work and return a null value ---- i forgot to mention... the div id=teste is inside another div... this is my error ?

Comment: First you need to change the xml to a valid xml i.e. currently tr tags are missing closing tr tags. ALso can you post the code you are currently using?

Comment: Nathan of course if you have another div containing your div you should test that scenario in the XPATH tester i sent you the link in the other comment...

Comment: I GOT... Now i've other question :S... How do i ignore the last tr tag and convert this to String ?

Comment: Only thing now is to dont pick up the last tr tag... convert to string i got :)..

Comment: Updated the post with an exmaple in C# along with the changed xpath query. Let me know if tht helps.

Comment: I didn't understand. Are you still getting null value?

Comment: Thanks MAN!! ... i'm a dumb ¬¬ ... i remove the tag tbody then WOrked perfectly, ALL, including the position last and the convert to string!!!...Sorry For the inconvenient.. THANKS CYBERNATE and THANKS for try to help me! *** If i want ask something about this code.. i just use this same thread or i open a new ASk ? ***

Answer (score 0):

Nathan you can use one of the thousand XPath tester online: http://www.futurelab.ch/xmlkurs/xpath.en.html this allows you to check quickly what you get whenever you change your xpath query, faster than waiting for an answer here :)

Comment: O.O !!! .... I dot know there's a tool like this.. i'll try.. But the same way ... i dont know much xpath query ... :/

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with:

```
trArray=document.getElementById('teste').getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

which will give you an array of all the TRs (assuming there's no tables inside the TRs)

If you want to find tags inside them then you can do something like

```
tagArray=trArray[0.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to get the tr's in .Net (not at client side/browser).